# Software implemented PLLs for signal synchronization, why use them?

Tags: pll

In short I'm recreating a program that reads 3 sinusoidal signals through an ADC performs some manipulations and then reproduces these signals through a DAC. In order to reproduce these signals I need the instantaneous phase of one of these manipulations. So I recreated a charge pump zero crossing pll in software.

I don't understand why you would go to the trouble of working out the analogue loop filter transfer function, convert it to the z domain, when in software when I could just implement a program that reads the amount of samples between zeros, and the instantaneous phase is just.

(current sample#-last zero sample#)/(pi*(number of samples between zeroes))

Now I've obviously missed something, but I don't know what to google to find out what.

Comment: Noise can introduce some jitter or ambiguity in the location of the zero crossings. A more robust alternative is the phase of the fundamental of the Fourier series, obtained by convolving with a sinusoid/cosinusoid, provided the frequency is well known.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you mean the frequency of the sinusoid i convolve it with is well known, because i dont know the frequency of the signal that i need the instantaneous phase of? I read a bit about using recursive discrete fourier transforms to achieve the same ends though i read allot of criticism that fourier transforms introduce large computational burdens.

Comment: If you know the frequency, there won't be a big burden, just two dot products. FFT is a much different matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For very high SNR signals locating the zero crossings will work pretty well.  You use PLL's when the signal doesn't have a high SNR, like the following.

[image: Noisy sinusoid]

As you can see by inspection, a zero-crossing algorithm wouldn't have a prayer of working on this signal.  A PLL, on the other hand, could do just fine.  That is, by the way, a tone with an SNR of 8 dB.

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying an analogue pll would work fine or are you saying that a zero crossing pll with a digital filter would work fine too(I know you can also use fft like you mentioned in a previous answer) ?

Comment: Oh and thank you for explaining why that algorithm wouldn't work, i knew it seemed to simple to be true.

Comment: I'm saying an analog or digital PLL would work, but I don't believe that a zero-crossing PLL with a digital filter would work.